# Python functions, how to insert from SQL statement and two DictReaders to Database

Tags: python, csv

I have written a script that reads specific columns from two csv files as well as a SQL statement to take a column from an excising table, with the intention to then insert those columns into a database table. I'm not sure how to store the data taken from those csv files and then insert them to a database table along with the data from the SQL statement. The code snippet is as below,

```
def importFirstDoc(filePath, path):
   with open(filePath, path) as csvFile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvFile)
    for row in reader:
        print(row["column1"])

    return;
importFirstDoc("C:\Development\\secDoc.csv", 'r')


def importSecDoc(filePath, path):
 with open(filePath, path) as csvFile:
    reader2 = csv.DictReader(csvFile)
    for row in reader2:
        print(row["column2"])
        print(row["column3"])
    return reader2;
importSecDoc("C:\Development\\firstDoc.csv", 'r')
```

I haven't included the SQL statement function just the CSV extracts. I'm not sure If I've explained what I'm attempting clearly, let me know if you need anymore information.

Comment: Do you need to store it for a long time, or can you insert it in the database immediately after reading from the CSV? Also what SQL database are you using (or planning on using)?

Comment: There's a number of issues here. When you call the functions, you're not assigning the return values to a name in the global scope, you're just throwing the data away. `importFirstDoc` doesn't actually return anything. You're only `printing` the values read from the files, so you're not storing the data anywhere even inside the functions. I suggest you drop the SQL requirement for now and focus on getting the data out of the CSVs correctly and in a usable format.

Comment: A proof-of-concept is not a working implementation. For now, the SQL part is on the horizon. We can't answer how to do that before you have a working starting basis.

Comment: With no indication on the table(s), the fields you want to extract from the CSV files, and where they should go in the table(s), the question is just *unclear*. I may help you with the Python part, but only if you make clear what you want to do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be useful to put the data in the same function. The following should create a generator that will yield the data from specific columns in two separate csv's as a tuple, which you can pass to some sql statement.

```
import csv

def importDocs(filename1, filename2):
    with open(filename1, "r") as csv1, open(filename2, "r") as csv2:  # open both files
        reader1 = csv.DictReader(csv1)
        reader2 = csv.DictReader(csv2)
        for row1, row2 in zip(reader1, reader2):  # for each row in the zipped readers
            yield (row1["column1"], row2["column2"], row2["column3"])  
            # yield specified columns as a tuple

for row in importDocs("firstDoc.csv", "secDoc.csv"):
    print(row)  # obviously not needed, just if you want to verify data
    #  ~~~  SQL insert with 'row' here  ~~~
```

EDIT: I forgot the 'zip' function around the readers in the function.

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't get this to run, giving me too many values(expected 2) error

Comment: @Liightslol You're right, my mistake, I'll update my answer momentarily. You need to throw a 'zip' around the readers in the function for loop.

Comment: @Liightslol Glad I could help. Yes, you can insert those three columns as separate SQL columns. I don't know what the syntax is for Microsoft SQL, but it is usually quite simple to pass a tuple or list to separate columns in an SQL table. Also yes, you can put any data you want in that yield statement in the function to return a tuple of whatever values to then insert into a database. If you didn't want to do it in the function, you could change the tuple to a list, and append the data after running the function.

Comment: @Liightslol it should be as simple as including it in the yield statement. alternatively, you could change the tuple in the yield statement to a list, and append the data to the yielded list after the function completes. Unrelatedly, if my answer has helped you, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to use the pandas, you can check [this link](https://repl.it/repls/NavajowhiteWorthlessDisassembly) for my suggested approach. In the script shared, I haven't included the part to import and export SQL table. 
I am assuming that you already know how to import a SQL table into python. If not, you can look for ways to import SQL table into pandas dataframe. Once you load the data in the pandas dataframe, it should be relatively easy to export it as a SQL table.

Following is the recreation of the script from the link shared.

```
import pandas as pd 
file1 = pd.read_csv("first_file.csv")
file2 = pd.read_csv("second_file.csv")
#Similarly the sql table can be imported to pandas df, let's call it sql_table1 

print(file1)
print(file2)

#copying the required columns
col1 = file1["Col 1"]
col2 = file2["Col 2"]
#col3 = sql_table["Col 3"], if the sql table is loaded to sql_table dataframe


#col3 can be added to this list of series
col12_series = [col1, col2]
col12_df = pd.concat(col12_series, axis=1)
print(col12_df)

#once you have the dataframe you can directly export pandas dataframe as a sql table
# this is where you could start:
# https://www.google.ca/search?q=export+pandas+dataframe+to+sql&oq=export+pandas+dataframe+to+sql&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.9119j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8
```